# .htaccess ErrorDocument 404 has superseded all my RewriteRule 301 redirects

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-404, http-status-code-301

I changed nearly all of the page names on my web site. No actual files or pages were deleted. I implemented a complete set of RewriteRule 301 redirects in .htaccess for all the old page names to the new page names. This all worked perfectly.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^/]*/)*index\.(html)?\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(([^/]*/)*)index\.(html)$  http://www.domain.co.uk/$1  [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^old-page-name.html$ http://www.domain.co.uk/new-page-name.html [R=301,L]
```

I have since created a 404.html page to catch traffic for incorrectly addressed backlinks and user typos in browser address bars, and implemented the relevant code in .htaccess to redirect incorrect URLs to my 404 page, after the 301 code above. This works, so if I try to access /ljdshfkkej.html, the /404.html page is displayed.

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
```

However, now this above 404 rule takes precedence over my 301 rules, so if someone tries to access /old-page-name.html, they no longer are redirected to /new-page-name.html but instead to /404.html. This isn't ideal but could be worse.

Is it possible to keep the 404 rule but to only have it activated for URLs that do not exist but for which there is no 301 redirect for? Or is it a case of either or?

Here is an overview of the entire code.

```
# .htaccess file last updated 2016/07/22

RewriteEngine on

# redirect index.html/php to root

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^/]*/)*index\.(html)?\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(([^/]*/)*)index\.(html)$  http://www.domain.co.uk/$1  [R=301,L]

# redirects from old pages

RewriteRule ^aboutus.html$ http://www.domain.co.uk/about-us.html [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^ammonia-test-kits-brand.html$ http://www.domain.co.uk/ammonia-test-kits.html [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^arsenic-free-fluoride-testing-brand.html$ http://www.domain.co.uk/fluoride-test-kit.html  [R=301,L]

# 404 error - page not found

ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
```

Comment: Put the complete htaccess file in question

Comment: Hi HJP, I included a more representative summary of the code now, and also as requested a dump of the whole file (with a few proper name changes made). Cheers.

Comment: Any comments? Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: I figured it out. The 404 redirect command needs to come before the 301 redirect rules in the .htaccess file. There is nothing wrong with any of the actual lines of code, just the sequence.